# Why can't we still use ctypes to call C++ from Python in 2019?

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes, abi

It still bugs me. After all, C has no fully standardized ABI either but it works with ctypes. Why the same can't be achieved for C++?

I've found this [blog post](http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/2007/07/21/ctypes-for-c-is/) that claims the issue is more political than technical, but is was written 12 years ago. Is this claim still accurate today?

Comment: *Is this claim still accurate today?* Pretty much.  It would require the C++ standard committee to standardize the C++ ABI.  To do that requires politics, not know-how.  This might actually come to fruition though, but I wouldn't advise holding your breath.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pybind11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can! (just not with ctypes)
https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

BUT, to accomplish that, it actually embeds a C++ interpreter for not much performance benefit.

One reason C++ doesn't have an official ABI is because compilers are so performance focused they need to cut across function and class boundaries to optimize. With different settings you might get different interfaces, even if it has the same ABI. A good example is return-value-optimization (RVO), which alters function signatures to avoid copying large structs.

Another reason is that C++ is super-meta, and most modern features depend on templates that generate code and recompile it. So you'd only be working with a subset of what makes C++ nice to code in.